# Table join with overrides

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables - actual and proposed - as follows:

```
ACTUAL
    Id|desc|Allocation|changeBit
    1|X|20||
    2|y|30||

PROPOSED
        Id|desc|Allocation|changeBit
        1|X|30|U|
        3|z|40|I|
```

The sought result is as follows:

```
    1|X|30|U|
    2|y|30||
    3|z|40|I|
```

A 'U' bit causes the record in 'proposed' to override 'actual'. 
An 'I' bit in proposed just indicates that the 'new' record needs to be added-on.

What would be the most elegant way to achieve this?

Ideally i would wish to avoid creation of temp tables followed by insert-update.
I am using sql-server 2008.

Comment: What happens if you have an `Allocation` other than 'U' in the `PROPOSED` table?

Comment: What happens if you have a row in `PROPOSED` that has an 'I' `Allocation`, but it already exists in `ACTUAL`?

Comment: It wont - the changebit is flagged from UI after necessary validations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to approach this with `union all` and `not exists`.  I find the `coalesce()` or `isnull()` on the columns in the `full outer join` approach to be inelegant.

```
select Id, desc, Allocation, changeBit
from proposed
union all
select Id, desc, Allocation, changeBit
from actual a
where not exists (select 1 from proposed p where a.id = p.id);
```

EDIT:

If you want the validation, it is essentially:

```
select Id, desc, Allocation, changeBit
from proposed
where changebit in ('U', 'I')
union all
select Id, desc, Allocation, changeBit
from actual a
where not exists (select 1 from proposed p where a.id = p.id);
```

Really testing for a valid "U" versus "I" is more intensive and seems unnecessary (and isn't really part of the original question).  You should probably ask another question, and explain exactly what you want done when there is an update to a non-actual record, or an insert for a record that doesn't exist.

Comment: Very nice suggestion.  I would make the minor suggestion of checking the `changeBit` field.  Currently neither your solution or mine handles inserts when an `ACTUAL` value already exists, or updates when it does not.

Comment: @JonSenchyna . . . The conditions "U" and "I" are equivalent in the sense that we choose the record from the proposed table.  The difference is that "U" expects an existing record and "I" doesn't.  We could (either of us) check for the conditions, but the OP doesn't say what to do in the case of a violation of this condition.  At least one of the comments says this is not important.

Comment: Although he did state that there should never be any bad rows in the `PROPOSED` table, I often like to be safe and assume that there could be bugs in the UI validation (or issues with multiple UIs attempting to make changes at the same time).

Comment: Overall, I will concede that this solution is much more elegant than the `FULL OUTER JOIN` one.  This became especially clear when I attempted to add the above-mentioned validation to both queries.  It is very easy to add such a filter to your query.

Comment: This solution is quite simple and elegant.For the sake of completeness,I would appreciate if the above discussed validation is put in too here.What would be the best way to put that in  - without harming the simplicity?

Answer (score 1):

You should join both tables using a `full outer join`, and then use `coalesce` to get the actual value only when a proposed value does not exist:

```
SELECT          COALESCE (p.id, a.id) AS id, 
                COALESCE (p.desc, a.desc) AS desc,
                COALESCE (p.allocation, a.allocation) AS allocation,
                COALESCE (p.changebit, a.changebit) AS changebit
FROM            actual a
FULL OUTER JOIN proposed p ON a.id = p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit off-base, but judging by your last statement, it looks like you are using this query to generate an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` statement.  Since you are using SQL-Server 2008, have you given thought to using the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to perform this all in one command, rather than three (query, insert, update)?

Assuming `PROPOSED` contains your changes, you could perform this like so:

```
MERGE ACTUAL AS A
USING PROPOSED AS P
    ON A.Id = P.Id
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE
    SET A.Allocation = P.Allocation
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT (Id, [Desc], Allocation)
    VALUES (Id, [Desc], Allocation);
```

Using this, you could drop the `changeBit` column, since the `MERGE` statement figures out for you if it's an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b9936/5/1)